# libEvent on Windows2008 server 64 or on ubuntu linux 13.0 server?

Tags: linux, windows, performance, libevent, iocp

Currently I'm developing a client-server system on windows2008 server R2 64, a server will comsume 2 or 3 clients, each client will send seperate binary message with 1.6k each to the server by 20Pc/second, that is, every 50ms the client will send a message (size: 1.6k) to server.

I supposed that libEvent is a good toolkit and have a good performance based questions Stackoverflow. And the libEvent version is 2.0.21.X64, it used I/O Completion Ports in windows platform, and the end user need to monitor the server status, they don't know how to use Ubuntu linux, so I selected windows 2008 server as the server.

However, after I developed the windows server program, it losts 30+ binary messages, but our application must be stable and all the messages must be received.

Are there something wrong on the windows network card settings? Or I should switch the server to Ubuntu server?

Thank you very much in advanced for your support!